# create/delete database in marklogic using rest api

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have created one rest-api instance in marklogic.I am able to delete/add the documents in some already existing database using curl easily.

Can somebody Please help on how to create n delete the database using curl command and how can we parameterized the command to delete associated forests and app-servers.

Also I am able to delete the rest-api instance that I created i.e, appserver itself but not associated database and forests.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 3):

You can create, delete, and modify app servers, databases, forests, and just about everything else through the [Management API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management). For instance, here's how you delete a forest called "example":

```
$ curl --anyauth --user user:password -X DELETE -i \
  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/forests/example?level=full
```

You can also delete a REST API app server, along with its content and modules databases and their forests, in one command:

```
$ curl --anyauth --user user:password -X DELETE -i \
  'http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis/RESTstop?include=content&include=modules'
```

Comment: Thanks dave.. That really helps a lot..!
I was wondering if we can get list of all the orphan forests in one go and delete them?

Comment: I tried 
curl --anyauth --user user:password -X DELETE -i \
  'http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis/RESTstop?include=content&include=modules'

But somehow the modules database and forests are not getting deleted.

Comment: Could you update your question with the full command you used and what curl's response was?

Comment: I used:
curl --anyauth --user user:password -X DELETE -i  http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis/restproj?include=content&include=modules

and response looked fine to me:


HTTP/1.1 202 Appserver deleted
Server: MarkLogic
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1735
Connection: close
<cluster-query xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/m
  <relations>
    <relation-group array="true">
      <typeref>databases</typeref>
      <relation-count units="quantity">2</relation-count>
      <relation array="true">
could not paste the entire msg here

Comment: It was able to delete the appserver,content-DB,all forests attached to content DB but modules DB and attached forests were not affected at all.

Comment: Did you put the URL for the curl command in single quotes? On *nix, the ampersand will be interpreted as splitting the command, viewing the "include=modules" section as a separate command, which will cause an error and fail to send that instruction to MarkLogic.

Comment: Thanks Dave.. putting url in double quotes worked for me here..! :)